# Limitation in Implementing IDataErrorInfo or INotifyDataErrorInfo in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo, inotifydataerrorinfo

I'm developing a WPF application (MVVM). I have a class from a separate assembly (Odata V4 Generated Proxy Class).

```
public partial class Book : BaseEntityType, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string Title{get;set;}
   ...
}
```

Now I need to decorate the properties of that class with data annotations, in order to validate the properties using either `IDataErrorInfo` or `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface.
Ex:

```
[Required]
public string Title{get;set;}
```

**Problem:**

As this class is in separate assembly, I cannot create a partial class.
Properties of this class are bounded to UI elements of application. Now I need to validate the properties, when user input's data.

I'm struggling to design the solution.
Could any one help me to acheive this?

Comment: You could use a wrapper to your data object, one that can implement INotifyPropertyChanged for binding to it, and have validation logic.
Your data object should still be stored, but you should also have a place to store your wrapper objects.

Comment: @Mishka, Providing code example will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper might look like this:

```
public class BookWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
   private Book _book;
     public Book Book 
   {
      get
       {
         return _book;
       }
      set
       {
         _book-value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("Book");
       }
   }  
    public string Error
    {
        get { return String.Empty; }
    }
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            String errorMessage = String.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Book":
                    if (Book.IsValid==false)
                    {
                        errorMessage = "Book not valid";
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return errorMessage;
        }
    }
  INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation...
}
```

This way you don't mess with your data object(Book) and you dont litter it with unnecessary interfaces.